# NSMutableDictionary is allocated and initialized with node but it is giving warning in soapdictionary

Tags: objective-c, soap, dictionary

```
+ (id) newWithNode:(CXMLNode*)node {
  return (id)[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithNode:node]autorelease];
 }
```

In this code MutableDictionary is allocated and initialized with node but it is giving warning in soapdictionary.How can we solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString *name=[[NSArray alloc] init];` is after a `return`, which will never run. If it is useless code and that's what the warning message is talking about, just remove this line of code.

Besides, initializing NSArray object and assign it to a NSString pointer makes no sense.

**Update**

`NSMutableDictionary` doesn't have `initWithNode:` method by default. I am not familiar with Sudzc (code.google.com/p/sudzc) but per your description I guess you are using this. Try to replace `NSMutableDictionary` with `SoapDictionary` if that's true. It implemented a `initWithNode:` method.

Comment: Sorry that line of code is not in the question ,It was a mistake

Comment: I got like NSMutableDcitionary may not respond to initWithNode:

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary` doesn't have `initWithNode:`. I am not familiar with Sudzc (http://code.google.com/p/sudzc) but per your description you should be using this. Try to replace `NSMutableDictionary` with `SoapDictionary` if that's true.

Comment: But Data handling when i do newWithNode it should return MutableDctionary rether then SoapDictionary so,I am confused which on i will use now

Comment: Per the implementation of `SoapDictionary` (http://code.google.com/p/sudzc/source/browse/trunk/Website/ObjC/Soap/SoapDictionary.h?r=150), if you are sure that `NSMutableDictionary` is what you need, then you can get it from the property `items` of `SoapDictionary`.